# gem not available, even after adding to gemfile and running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm making a simple task where I need to parse an XML Http response, all the http is working fine, and I have my xml string....

I'm trying to use the `xml-simple` gem.

I've `gem install xml-simple`

I've also added `gem 'xml-simple'` to the gemfile

Ran `bundle install` with success

but when I try to `require 'xml-simple'` in my rake task it fails saying `no such file to load -- xml-simple`...

What am I missing???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bundler tries to load the gem by using the gem name as the require path (i.e. `require 'xml-simple'`). But in the case of the `xml-simple` gem, the path is `xmlsimple`, not `xml-simple`.

So in your Gemfile, use this instead:

```
gem 'xml-simple', :require => 'xmlsimple'
```

Comment: @jondavidjohn It's gem specific. Newer gems usually follow the convention. The error message is quite indicative though. So when you see that, just check the gem's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Gems sometimes have a different require path than the gem name, try either:

`gem 'xml-simple', :require => 'xml/simple'`

or

`gem 'xml-simple', :require => 'xmlsimple'`

or whatever the correct require path is to specify